# Disable filter in a custom column in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, sales-order

I am using layout handles in adding custom column to my Orders grid. How can i disable the filtering input field?

Here is my code:
**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/company**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="addColumnAfter">
            <columnId>printed</columnId>
            <arguments>
                <header>Printed</header>
                <index>printed</index>
                <width>80</width>
                <renderer>Company_myModule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Printed</renderer>
                <type>text</type>
            </arguments>
            <after>status</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_order_grid_update_handle>
<adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
    <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
</adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
    <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

[image: my image]

**Printed.php**

```
<?php
 class Mjsi_Orderprint_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Printed extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
    $value =  $row->getData();
    $value = $value['entity_id'];

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
     */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    /**
     * Retrieve our table name
     */
    $table = $resource->getTableName('orderprint/orderprint');


    $query = 'SELECT orderprint_id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE order_id = '
             . $value . ' LIMIT 1';

    /**
     * Execute the query and store the result in $sku
     */
    $value = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
    //return $value;


    if($value) {return '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Yes</span>';}
    else {return '<span style="color:#900; font-weight:bold;">No</span>';}
    ///return '<span style="color:#900;">'.$value.'</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<filter>false</filter>` Hope it works :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>printed</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Printed</header>
                    <index>printed</index>
                    <width>80</width>
                    <filter>false</filter> // add this code
                    <renderer>Company_myModule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Printed</renderer>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>status</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: This <filter>false</filter> don't works .

Comment: may be try using 0 or 1 instead of true false

Comment: Still does not work. I want that field to disappear.

Comment: Please try my updated code

Comment: page does not work.

Comment: can you please add your renderer file?

Comment: Please see my edited post.